# Replace outerHTML without detaching element

Tags: javascript, html, outerhtml

Have a DOM node (ie: `<p id="myNode">hello world</p>`) and a raw string containing it's new replacement.

What's a good technique to effectively achieve...

```
var rawReplacement = `<p id="myNode" updated=true foo="bar">hello world!!!</p>`
document.getElementById("myNode").outerHTML = rawReplacement
```

But without actually using outerHTML (which detaches the original element from the DOM; losing events, etc).

Comment: Are you just trying to change the attributes `updated=true` and `foo="bar"`, and the text of the paragraph?

Comment: The accepted answer needs to accommodate for any number of attributes, not just updated and foo.

Comment: The 2 answers submitted, mine and waterfoul's, should account for any number of attributes.

Comment: It needs to be agnostic to both the template and the existing DOM element; a re-usable function that could take any template string and any existing DOM node and copy all attributes from said template to the existing DOM node.  So Ie: parse the attributes from the template, then loop over them to apply to the DOM node.

Comment: you are going to write a custom function to handle that. Unfortunately there is no out of the box solution for this. What is the use case? I will update my answer with an example solution you could try.

Comment: Sure, well the use case is rather long-winded but essentially I have a bunch of existing DOM elements, some logic happens after the page load to compute a new replacement for them (a raw string, such as in the example - this replacement string is also unique for each element) and so the idea is to loop over each element and apply this theoretical magicOuterHTML function to apply the new template.  Replacing them with just outerHTML would work fine but it breaks the existing DOM tree; that needs to remain intact.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably do something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myNode");

el.setAttribute('updated', true);
el.setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
el.textContent = 'new text';
```

**Edit:**
For this to be more dynamic you could possibly write a function like the one below to loop over an object of attributes and their values and apply them to the target element.

It seems like what you are looking to achieve is pretty difficult with vanilla javascript, I would look into using some sort of library, possibly react, as it seems like you are looking to make changes based on state.

```
// Function
function updateElement (element, attributes) {
  for (attr in attributes) {
    element.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr]);
  }
}


// Use
var myNode = document.getElementById("myNode");
var attributes = {
    updated: true,
    foo: bar
};

updateElement(myNode, attributes);
```

Comment: Looks good thanks, this would do the trick!  (along with a quick update to the innerHTML)

Comment: Yes exactly, the changes are based on new state.  However, a goal for this is actually *not* to use React or any framework - something lower level to perform just the diff/attribute and inner text would be ideal.   Extra points if it can accommodate for not only the target DOM 'outer element' but it's children too (ie- so any children are not detached either).

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will want to mutate the element to make each change individually. To make the changes you showed you will want to do the following

```
document.getElementById("myNode").setAttribute('updated', true);
document.getElementById("myNode").setAttribute('foo', 'bar');
document.getElementById("myNode").textContent = 'hello world!!!';
```

If you want to use this on any element you will need to change the argument passed to getElementById to match your element's ID.

Using setAttribute will work for most attributes and works in the format setAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue). For details about how setAttribute works I would recommend looking at the mdn docs as they explain the caviats pretty extensively (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

For setting the interior of the element you will need to set the innerHtml property if you are adding html or the textContent property if assigning text only (useful as you shouldn't need to escape html)

Comment: Thanks, to clarify however the answer needs to be agnostic to both the template and the existing DOM element (other than id).  Assume initially that we don't know the number of attributes or the attribute name/values of the template, nor it's innerText.

Comment: Done, I went with the browser api explanation approach instead of offering a function which does what the apis do